# How to prevent validating from being fired when I click X (Close button) on the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation

This is a winform C# question. I have a textbox with a validating event listener to validate the content of the textbox. Say, the textbox doesn't accept negative values. I only listen to validating event so by default, the textbox's AutoValidate property is EnablePreventFocusChange, which is totally fine for me.

The problem is, when I click the X button on the right top corner of the form, I don't want the validation to be fired because I am closing the form anyway. How can I do this? There is no control to set CauseValidation to false, which I can do if there is a closing button. Thank you very much.

Comment: To prevent raising `Validating` event of the focused control, you need to override `WndProc` and handle `WM_CLOSE` to not raise `Validating` of the focused control. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48484847/3110834).

Comment: [Prevent raising of Validating event of focused control when Closing the form](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/prevent-raising-of-validating-event-of-focused-control-when-closing-the-form/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, the only way I would think to do it is to set `AutoValidate` on the form to false and handle validation in the controls manually.  The form has `.Validate()` and `.ValidateChildren()` methods, read up on these as they are what you need to perform validation.  To handle it manually, you will need to listen for when a control is losing focus - if validation fails you then need to perhaps re-focus the offending control.

Alternatively, make the form `ControlBox = false;` to remove the X button.

**Update:** Alternatively again you can use a member variable to test whether to validate or not (ie, whether the form is closing or not).  You cannot do this using the `FormClosing` event as this fires after the validation, however you can detect form closing via `WndProc`.  Code is provided in this post:

http://technoblot.wordpress.com/2006/09/08/winforms-causesvalidation-not-working-a-workaround/

A slightly less involved workaround.

Comment: So it seems that no easy workaround for this issue if I would like to stick to individual control validation. Obviously, to me, removing the X button is not a solution. But thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: All solutions will be workarounds, I happen to have found an easier alternative after a little searching - the answer has been amended to show this.

Answer (score 3):

When closing the form, the form checks if the `AutoValidate` property of the form has a value different from `Disabled` then it raises the `Validating` event of the focused control. Also if there is any validation error (by setting `e.Cancel = true` in the Validating event), it prevents closing of the form.

To prevent raising the Validating error when closing the form, you need to override `WndProc` and before processing `WM_CLOSE` message set `AutoValidate` to `Disabled` and after that, set it back to original value. The reason for setting it back to original value is because you may want to prevent closing the form and then it's expected the value of `AutoValidate` be the same value that the developer has been set originally:

```
private const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_CLOSE)
    {
        var autoValidate = this.AutoValidate;
        this.AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        this.AutoValidate = autoValidate;
    }
    else
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

**Note:** If you just want to allow the form get closed after click on close button, it's enough to override `OnClosing` method and set `e.Cancel = false` after calling `base.OnClose`. But it doesn't prevent the `Validating` event. It just allows the form get closed even if there is a validation error in the focused control.

You can read more about the problem in this post: [Prevent raising of Validating event of focused control when Closing the form](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/prevent-raising-of-validating-event-of-focused-control-when-closing-the-form/).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by setting the form CausesValidation property to False.
The form now closes normally when I click the X button.

Comment: Setting `CausesValidation` of the form is useless.