# Click Event Not Firing - Cannot Change Focus - Cannot Close Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a Windows Forms Application. I have several forms in this application (a main form, and several specialized forms), and on only one form, click events are not firing for any of my buttons.

It is not that the code in the handler is broken. This can be determined by the fact that a breakpoint on the first line of the handler is never reached when clicking the button.

Other events are working (I'm using `CheckedChanged` events on this form and they are behaving).

My team members have reviewed, and also can't spot the problem.

Here is a simplified view of my code:

**Designer Generated Code**

```
partial class MyForm
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button addButton;

    private void InitalizeComponent()
    {
        this.addButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.addButton.Name = "addButton";
        // Drawing statements here
        this.addButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.addButton_Click);

        this.Controls.Add(this.addButton);
    }
}
```

**My Code**

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The debugger is not reaching a break point on this line");
    }
}
```

**Edit: Additional Information from Testing**

There are several data-bound dropdownlists in my form. I have discovered that the click event only fails to fire if I make a selection in a drop down box first.

If I make no selections, the break point in the button's handler fires. Otherwise it doesn't. There are no events registered on these drop down lists.

Comment: is there some other code in your form which is removing the wiring between event & handler after 'InitializeComponent' is called ?

Comment: Can you think of an example of something that can do that?
I'll have a look now, but I don't know what to look for that could undo that wiring.

Comment: Is your button enabled?

Comment: Enabled is currently set to True, but that's definitely the right line of thought.

Comment: @JamieButler : I have a question - Is your button clickable ? I mean when you click on it , do you see the visual appearance of it getting pressed & then released ?

Comment: @Kapoor I do get the depressed and released animation when clicking the button

Comment: @JamieButler, then the wiring between event & its handler is not the issue. Your button seems to be disabled  (I guess it looks frozen & grayed out).  Some part of the code is disabling the button.

Comment: @Kappor You may have misread, I **do** get the correct animation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Here is the reason:**

When using data binding, when you enter a value in a data bound control, it first tries to validate entry and then if the entry was valid, data binding will put the value in data source, but if a validation error occurs validation returns false and your control goes to invalid mode.

When a child control of form didn't validate, by default you can not change focus from invalid control.

Click on a button by default causes validation of the control that are losing the focus, so you can't click on button, as you see your button reflect to mouse but not actually click.

The same problem will happen if you handle `Validating` event of a control like `TextBox` and set `e.cancel = true`.

**Here is the fix:**

you can fix this behavior using either of following options:

- Set [`CausesValidation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of your button to `false`
- Set [`AutoValidate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.autovalidate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of your form to `AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange`

Comment: Thank you, this has given me a full understanding of what was producing the error. I had managed to fix it, without understanding why it was broken or why it was now fixed.

Comment: such a good explanation and very clear fix. I had been seeing this problem for a long time without any solution. thanks.

Comment: @smoothumut You may also find this post useful: [How to prevent validating from being fired when I click X (Close button) on the form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48484847/3110834)

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick for you

Change

```
public ScheduleMeeting()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

to

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: How does `public ScheduleMeeting()` compile in that class? Strange it is.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: I agree with you

Comment: Very sorry about that, it was something I forgot to change while copying my code across and simplifying it for the question.

In my actual code, the class is called "ScheduleMeeting", but for this example I renamed it "MyForm"

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered the issue after further testing.

I the issue is not with button events, but with the form becoming blocked after making a selection from a drop down box.

I have not yet discovered why the form blocks after the drop down is selected (it has no events, but does have databinding, so there are some possible causes there).

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I posed the reason based on your answer. Hope you find it helpful:)