# C# Whenever 2 Forms are opened the original one's click event's wont fire

Tags: c#, winforms

As the title says I instantiate new form like this :

```
Form newWindow = new Form
{
    ShowIcon = false,
    MinimizeBox = false,
    MaximizeBox = false,
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
    Size = new Size(270, 120),
    Owner = this,
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
    AutoValidate = AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange
};
newWindow.Show();
```

While the `newWindow` form is shown the owner form's click events wont fire. How can I fix that ?

Comment: It's hard to guess what's exactly the problem. But maybe there is a validation error in your first form which prevents focus change from a control to buttons. Try set `AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange` for your first form. You may find this post helpful. [Winforms Click Event Not Firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162003/winforms-click-event-not-firing)

Comment: I've just pasted your code into a simple project with a form with two buttons, one has your code in it and the other just throws a MessageBox.  If I click the button that create your new form then I can still click a button on the original form and get the MessageBox.  So your code, from what we have, seems OK.  Reza may have a point on validates but could you try simplifying your parent form?