# Textbox validation not allowing form to close

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form that validates if there is text in a text box, which works well when going through the rest of the form,  however, if the user just wants to click the close(x) button in the upper right corner instead of actually running the application, I get the exception handling message of text not being in the text box instead of the application exiting.  I looked around here and looked at other questions in regards to detecting the close button being pushed and that led me to trying the below. I'm still getting the event message instead of exiting.  How can I bypass this message when the close button is clicked?

As it stands now, the only way I can close the application is if I put something into the text box and then click the close (x) button.

```
private void testTextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {


        //check to see if there is anything entered into the main text box before choosing an option
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(testTextBox.Text))
        {
            if (sender.Equals(CloseReason.UserClosing))
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have not entered anything to work with. \n Please enter something.");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you manually calling this method? I don't see any reason why sender would be an enum value.

Comment: This method is being called when the user tries to click on any other control within the form. In order for the other controls to work there needs to be something within this specific textbox. This is why I am using the validating event on the textbox to check if there is anything entered into it. But if the user decides to just close the application with the close button instead of entering in something into this text box I either am in a loop of getting the message box I am calling within the validating method or I have to enter something within that text box and then click the close button.

Comment: Do you still need a solution?

Comment: You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48484847/3110834).

Answer (score 0):

I have made two forms:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

And the other one:

```
  public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
            {
              Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            base.OnClosing(e);
        }
    }
```

It works for me. If I close form2 with text in textblock it exits the app.

Comment: Should I not be doing the validation in the textbox validating event, but instead do the validation within the form OnClosing event?

Comment: You should override the OnClosing if you want to validate when click on X. Otherways it won't be exception safe. :)

Comment: Tigyi  I'm not sure you are understanding what I'm trying to do.  I don't want to validate when closing the form/application. I'm wanting to validate the textbox for all instances except when interacting with the form control box of closing the form.

Comment: Do you still need a solution?

Comment: @JánosTigyi Not a good solution. What about cases that there are multiple controls having `Validating` event? To see the solution take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48484847/3110834).

Comment: I missunderstood the question. "Textbox validation not allowing form to close" ... Id doesn't say prevent from...