# UserControl Validating function is called even when AutoValidate is set to Disable on both the UC's design and the UC's instance

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, user-controls

1. Created a UserControl with many data bound child controls on it, none of which have Validating events.
2. Gave the root of the UC a Validating event.
3. Set the root of the UC to **AutoValidate:Disabled**
4. Placed the UC on a main form.
5. Set the UC instance's properties on the main form to **AutoValidate:Disabled**
6. Main form has Edit, Save, Cancel buttons. Only Save calls uc.ValidateChildren().

Expected result: Validation function only called when I click Save on main form.

Actual result: Validation function is also called when I click Cancel on main form. I greatly desire that it *not* be called, because this is the whole point of a Cancel button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main question is: do you want automatic validation?

◾ If you don't want automatic validation at form level:

- Set [AutoValidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.autovalidate?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the Form to [`Disable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autovalidate?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#fields) and no `Validating` event will raise when you move between controls.
- Call `ValidateChildren` when you want to trigger validating events.

◾ If you want automatic validation at form level, but you don't want validation when clicking X button or a Cancel button:

- Set the [AutoValidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.autovalidate?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the Form to [`EnableAllowFocusChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autovalidate?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#fields).
- For your Cancel button make sure you have set [CausesValidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property to `false`.
- To prevent validating when closing the form, add the following code to your form:

  ```
   private const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
   {
       if (m.Msg == WM_CLOSE)
       {
           var autoValidate = this.AutoValidate;
           this.AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
           base.WndProc(ref m);
           this.AutoValidate = autoValidate;
       }
       else
           base.WndProc(ref m);
   }
  ```

  You may want to take a look at my post here for more details: [How to prevent validating from being fired when I click X (Close button) on the form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48484847/3110834).

Comment: I tried the "CausesValidation property of your cancel button to false" thing before posting, based on some older SO answers. It did nothing. (My main form is not a modal dialog, and is never being closed.)

Comment: I believe AutoValidate = Disable is supposed on the form based on my linked post :)

Comment: This edit is clearer, yeah :) The MS documentation on this topic didn't help me reason my way to the solution. I found it by luck. The docs don't really convey how scope is the real culprit here (root of main form scope versus UC instance scope versus UC design scope). :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case the fix was:

7. Set **the root of the main form** to **AutoValidate:Disabled**. Merely setting this on the instance of the UC was not sufficient.

Comment: Title of the question is telling you have already set AutoValidate of Form to Disable.

Comment: Updated the title to more reflect the original problem.