# How to Use TextBox Event Changed so that it does not always appear messagebox when typing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable, binding, textbox

How to Use TextBox Event Changed so that it does not always appear messagebox when typing in vb.net.

Actually I use the textbox changed event if it does not match from the database then a messagebox will appear whether there is something wrong with my code. Please Guide me.

Thanks

```
 Private connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\demo.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    Private Sub Form7_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim acsCustomers As AutoCompleteStringCollection = New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
        For Each dr As DataRow In Me.GetData().Rows
            acsCustomers.Add(dr("CODEPRODUCT").ToString())
        Next
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = acsCustomers
    End Sub
    Private Function GetData() As DataTable
        Dim conString As String = connectionString
        Dim query As String = "select CODEPRODUCT from Items"
        Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(conString)
            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                Using sda As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Using dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        Return dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim rows As DataRow() = Me.GetData().Select("CODEPRODUCT='" & TextBox1.Text.Trim() & "'")
        If rows.Length = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select From List Only")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: try another event like leave so that the program knows that you will not enter any more characters

Comment: @nbk , thanks I tried the leave event as your suggestion but it does not display the messagebox if it does not match the database

Comment: what happens when set there a stop point and go line by line

Comment: @nbk , you mean event `Textbox1_Leave` . Is it true?

Comment: no on `if rows.length`  it must be bigger than 1 as it would else show the message box

Comment: @nbk ,you mean `if rows.length > 0 then`

Comment: You may consider that a _MessageBox_ may not be appropriate for your situation.

Comment: yes exactly @siwa86

Comment: If it didn't work when you handled the `Leave` event then you did it wrong. As you haven't shown us what you did or explained what actually happened when you did it, we can't tell what's wrong with it. It sounds to me like you should actually be handling the `Validating` event. That event exists for the purposes of validating. If the data doesn't pass validation, you set `e.Cancel` to `True` and the control will not lose focus, so the user has to fix the data.

Comment: Why not just use a `ComboBox` set to DropDownList?

Comment: @jmcilhinney , thank you for your advice

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid , `You may consider that a MessageBox may not be appropriate for your situation.` 
because I have to use a messagebox to provide notifications or warnings to users

Comment: @HardCode , `Why not just use a ComboBox set to DropDownList? ` 
because I prefer to use textbox

Comment: @siwa86: _because I have to use a messagebox to provide notifications or warnings to users_:  Using _MessageBox_ isn't mandatory, it's a choice. One could use _StatusStrip_ or other controls. As with anything in life, some _choices_ may result in making one's life more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several points here to consider.

First of all, the `GetData()` function returns a disposed object because you are using the `Using` statement to create it. What's the point of returning a disposed object, ready to be collected and destroyed?

You should have instead:

```vb
Private Function GetData() As DataTable
    Dim conString As String = connectionString
    Dim query As String = "SELECT CODEPRODUCT FROM Items"
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(conString),
        cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con),
        sda As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        sda.Fill(dt)
    End Using

    Return dt
End Function
```

Second of all, you shouldn't validate while the text is changing and execute database queries that much. Get the input as a whole and validate it. And speaking of the database. Look carefully at your code and you'll find that you no longer need to access it anymore to validate a product code. You have them all filled in the `TextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource` collection and you can use it instead as the products source.

For example, in the `Validating` event:

```vb
Private Sub Form7_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim acsCustomers As New AutoCompleteStringCollection

    Using dt As DataTable = GetData()
        acsCustomers.AddRange(
            dt.AsEnumerable().
            Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("CODEPRODUCT")).ToArray())
    End Using

    TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = acsCustomers
    AutoValidate = AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    Dim product = TextBox1.Text.Trim()
    Dim products = TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Cast(Of String)

    If product.Length > 0 AndAlso products.Any() AndAlso
        Not products.Contains(product, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select From List Only...")
        e.Cancel = True
        TextBox1.SelectAll()
        ' Or
        ' TextBox1.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

Remove the `product.Length > 0` condition if the user should select something. Also, you can force validation on command key press by calling the [`Form.ValidateChildren`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.validatechildren?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Form.ValidateChildren)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) method.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Me.ValidateChildren()
    End If
End Sub
```

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48484847/14171304) solution for example to close the `Form` when the user clicks the close button. Setting `Me.AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable` is enough though if you don't have an option to cancel closing the `Form`.

```vb
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg = &H10 Then
        Dim av = Me.AutoValidate
        Me.AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
        Me.AutoValidate = av
        Return
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Do note, in a data-entry Form, you should set its [CancelButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Form.CancelButton)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) property to a **Cancel** button whose [CausesValidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.CausesValidation)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) property is set to `False`. This tells the `Form` to bypass the `Me.ValidateChildren` routine.

Side note, no need to execute a database `SELECT` query and fill a `DataTable` object to only check whether or not a product exists. Run a `COUNT` query instead. In other words, call your `GetData` method to create and fill `AutoCompleteStringCollection` object, and create another method to execute a `COUNT` command. Again, this is a side note and as I mentioned earlier, you don't need the *count* method in this context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
sorry I was late in responding to you. if I use `TextBox1_Validating` Why is it that if I close the form then the message box appears, is there something wrong with me?

Comment: @siwa86 See the edit.

Comment: The additional answer from you is perfect. Sorry I replied late. How do I handle in the textbox if I use a backspace keyboard and esc should appear messagebox but if I enter then the messagebox appears?   and for this `Side note, no need to execute a database SELECT query and fill a DataTable object to only check whether or not a product exists. Run a COUNT query instead.` If I use query `count` then the autocomplete list will not appear in the textbox

Comment: @siwa86 Set `AutoValidate = AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange` in the `Load` event. As for the `COUNT` query, read the clarification in my last edit.

Comment: Thank you for your additional answer and sorry I was late responding to you. `Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then Me.ValidateChildren()         ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Back AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then  Me.ValidateChildren()  End If   End Sub` . I tried pressing the backspace and esc keyboard keys, can I apply it directly to the message box without `enter`

Comment: @siwa86 This has nothing to do with the problem that I provided a solution for it here. New questions for new requirements please. Besides, what you are asking here does not make sense. Why do you need to validate on pressing `Back` or/and `Esc` keys? Forward that to a new question asking how to trap pressing multiple keys or whatever you are trying to do. Search for duplicates before that.

Comment: OK, I'll make a new question. `Why do you need to validate on pressing Back or/and Esc keys?` because when the user presses the keyboard keys backspace and esc without enter there is a problem that the user can choose outside of the list, please can you help me on a new question

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227385/how-to-handle-in-textbox-when-the-user-presses-multiple-keys-in-vb-net)  this is the link of my new question, please guide me