# how to handle in textbox when the user presses multiple keys in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

how to handle in textbox when the user presses multiple keys in vb.net.

When the user presses the keyboard keys backspace and esc without enter there is a problem that the user can choose outside of the list. Please Guide Me.
This is the code below after modification of the recommendations and guidelines @dr.null

Thanks

```
 
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form7
Private connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dapperdemo.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If m.Msg = &H10 Then
            Dim av = Me.AutoValidate
            Me.AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
            Me.AutoValidate = av
            Return
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
 Private Sub Form7_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim acsCustomers As New AutoCompleteStringCollection

        Using dt As DataTable = GetData()
            acsCustomers.AddRange(
                dt.AsEnumerable().
                Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("CODEPRODUCT")).ToArray())
        End Using

        TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = acsCustomers
        'AutoValidate = AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange
    End Sub
Private Function GetData() As DataTable
        Dim conString As String = connectionString
        Dim query As String = "SELECT CODEPRODUCT FROM Items"
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(conString),
            cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con),
            sda As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            sda.Fill(dt)
        End Using

        dt.AcceptChanges()
        Return dt
    End Function
 Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
        Dim product = TextBox1.Text.Trim()
        Dim products = TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Cast(Of String)

        'If product.Length > 0 AndAlso products.Any() AndAlso
        If products.Any() AndAlso
    Not products.Contains(product, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select From List Only...")
            e.Cancel = True
            TextBox1.SelectAll()
            ' Or
            ' TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub
  Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            Me.ValidateChildren()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Screenshot Form7]

Comment: why have a Textbox at all, you can remove all non ascii characters vefore parsing it. But basically simpler it would be to use a Pull-Down and check if a index was selected

Comment: I don't see any code related to key presses there so what's the actual issue? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: Forget this keys thing and in your save/add/insert/ok/whatever button click event handler, call this first `If Not Me.ValidateChildren() Then Return`. This prevents insert/update a record if any validation fails.

Comment: @nbk , you mean combo box

Comment: yes i mean combobox

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Actually this is related to the previous post so I made a new question

Comment: @dr.null , Thank you for your reply. I know what you mean by using the click event button, but can it be done directly from the validation textbox?

Comment: @nbk , but I still want to use a textbox

Comment: i would test textbox1.leave or lost focus and check the value against  a list, when it fits ok if there is no match delete input and write a message box

Comment: What previous post? If you're expecting me to remember a specific question of the many I view every day then you'll be disappointed. As always, this question should be self-contained and provide all information relevant to the current issue, not relying on any existing knowledge. Are you asking about key presses or not? If you are then where's the code related to key presses? If you're just asking about validating data then key presses are irrelevant and just obfuscate the issue. You need to be clear about what the actual problem is. If the question is about validation, say that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Oh, I remembered [the previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77170781/how-to-validate-the-autocomplete-textbox-so-that-the-user-does-not-type-outside#comment136044820_77170781) right away, when I saw the first comment here, `...basically simpler it would be to use a Pull-Down`

Comment: Assuming you only have that textbox in the Form that you need to validate its inputs. Implement the `Leave` event of that textbox and paste `If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then If Not Me.ValidateChildren() Then TextBox1.Select()`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , ` If the question is about validation` Sorry for the late reply, yes it's true this is for validation and also related to keypress

Comment: @dr.null , `Assuming you only have that textbox in the Form that you need to validate its inputs. Implement the Leave event of that textbox and paste If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then If Not Me.ValidateChildren() Then TextBox1.Select()`  
Thank you for your reply. Sorry I was late in replying. 
I tried your code but when I pressed the keyboard backspace and esc the message box from the validation event still didn't appear

Comment: No, it will if you handle the `Leave` event of the **TextBox1**.

Comment: @dr.null , so how can I handle when the user presses the keyboard backspace and esc then the result is from a textbox outside the list then the messagebox appears `Please Select From List Only...`

Comment: I don't know what else to suggest. You wanted to validate and allow selecting another control even when the validation fails and we suggested to `AutoValidate = AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange`. You wanted to bypass the validation and close the Form when click its close button and we suggested the `WndProc` override part. Now, you want to not allow the user to leave that textbox until a valid input is entered. I'm lost.

Comment: @dr.null , `Now, you want to not allow the user to leave that textbox until a valid input is entered.` this is exactly what I want

Comment: @dr.null , please guide me and give it as your answer. I'm sure you can provide a solution for me

Comment: Then comment the `AutoValidate = AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange` line, ignore the `Leave` event suggestion, omit the `product.Length > 0` condition, select the text box and set its `TabIndex` property to `0`. Try and see how it goes.

Comment: @dr.null , `Then comment the AutoValidate = AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange` for this line code commentout, event textbox `leave` I did a commentout too and `omit the product.Length > 0 condition`I have also removed this from the textbox validating event and `select the text box and set its TabIndex property to 0` I have also done this but it remains the same

Comment: Screenshot your Form and post it. Edit the code block and add everything in that Form.

Comment: @dr.null , sorry i am late in your response , I have updated screenshots and updated code according to your request

Comment: Seriously? Is that all? No, unless you close the Form, the message box will show up if `TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource` collection does not contain the `TextBox1.Text` value. I can't reproduce what you claim.

Comment: @dr.null , sorry I'm late to reply. `Seriously? Is that all?` yes, that's all serious. `unless you close the Form, the message box will show up if TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource collection does not contain the TextBox1.Text value.` 
Please guide me on what I should change, I will follow your recommendations

Comment: If you mean, by any chance, to force validation on `Back` key press, then that's a wrong thing to do. What you have is enough no matter which keys are pressed. The textbox will always be selected, and the message box will show up as long as the input is invalid. Big Period.

Comment: @dr.null , Sorry I'm late in replying, but if the user presses the backspace and esc keys without `Keys.Enter`, this will prevent the message box from appearing.

Comment: `If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then Me.ValidateChildren()`.

Comment: @dr.null , Sorry I was late replying and I tried your additional code, only I had to press the escape key twice

Answer (score 0):

This answer will involve a `ComboBox`. Try it and see if it feels ok. You will see that it will not allow the user to even select an item not in the list when the `DropDownStyle` is set to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`. This seems to be the behavior you are looking for, as the `TextBox` is too permissive.

I'm going to move your database query off the UI. The query may be quick, but I won't provide an answer with a database query on the UI in either case. If the query is slow, you will notice an improvement in UI performance.

```vb
Private Function GetCodeProducts() As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim result As String()
    Using dt As New DataTable(),
            con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT CODEPRODUCT FROM Items", con),
            sda As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        sda.Fill(dt)
        dt.AcceptChanges() ' is this really necessary?
        result = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("CODEPRODUCT")).ToArray()
    End Using
    Return result
End Function

Private Function GetCodeProductsAsync() As Task(Of IEnumerable(Of String))
    Return Task.Run(AddressOf GetCodeProducts)
End Function
```

There's no reason to return a `DataTable`. You just need an enumerable of string so there it is. The non-async function can be contained inside the async one as a lambda if you don't care about defining both.

```vb
Private Async Sub Form7_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim codeProducts = Await GetCodeProductsAsync()

    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(codeProducts.ToArray())
    ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
    ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown

End Sub
```

Notice that Form_Load, a UI method, is now marked `Async`, and we `Await` the result of the task which returns your data from the database.

Populate the `ComboBox.Items` and set some AutoComplete related properties on the control. Also notice there is no `WndProc` or additional validation required for the control. *This code will behave exactly as your current version with a `TextBox`*, and without the additional code I just mentioned.

If you change the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`, then the user will not be allowed to select anything other than an item in the list. The validation is built in. You may not like the feel of this.

```vb
ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```

Using the `DropDown` style, you can perform validation to force the user to enter something in the list. This has autocomplete as you want. However it is very restrictive and will not allow the user to leave the `ComboBox` until he chooses something in the list

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Validating
    If Not ComboBox1.Items.Contains(ComboBox1.Text.Trim()) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select From List Only...")
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: _dt.AcceptChanges() ' is this really necessary?_ **Yes**. When you fill it, and when you update the DB. Otherwise, the rows retain wrong [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowstate?view=net-7.0#definition) and you won't benefit from useful methods such as `RejectChanges`, `GetChanges`, `Select`, ...etc. Useful properties like `DataView.RowStateFilter`, `DataView.RowFilter`, ...etc.

Comment: @dr.null, actually, that explicit call is not necessary. You're correct that it is necessary that `AcceptChanges` be called but `Fill` and `Update` already do that internally by default. All data adapters inherit the properties `AcceptChangesDuringFill` and `AcceptChangesDuringUpdate` and both are `True` by default. An example of where you might set the former to `False` is if you wanted retrieve records from one database and insert them into another. An example of where you might set the latter to `False` is if you wanted to insert changes into two database tables.

Comment: @djv , thank you for your answer, I tried your code when I typed it then the autocomplete appeared and then I chose from the list then I used the keyboard backspace and esc the results were outside the list but the message box didn't come out and if I closed the form the message box appeared

Comment: @jmcilhinney Agree. However, explicit set is required if you don't use adapters to do so.

Comment: @djv , thank you for your answer, I tried your code when I typed it then the autocomplete appeared and then I chose from the list then I used the keyboard backspace and esc the results were outside the list but the message box didn't come out and if I closed the form the message box appeared

Comment: @siwa86 when do you expect the validation to occur? It happened when you closed the form because you left the control and that is when it is occurring. The problem `the user can choose outside of the list` is solved two different ways in this solution. Did you try both styles of `ComboBox.DropDownStyle`? You should be clear about the exact desired behavior. When exactly do you want the message shown?

Comment: @djv ,  sorry I'm late to reply. `when do you expect the validation to occur?` I want to not allow the user to leave that combobox until a valid input is entered. `Did you try both styles of ComboBox.DropDownStyle?` I I just tried one `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown`. `You should be clear about the exact desired behavior. When exactly do you want the message shown?` when the user types then the autocomplete appears if the user does on the keyboard backspace and esc then the results are outside the list then the message box appears

Comment: @djv , `Did you try both styles of ComboBox.DropDownStyle? ` I've used ComboBox.DropDownStyle. so I prefer to use comboxstyle.dropdown because I can do autocomplete typing.  so when the user types then the autocomplete appears if the user does on the keyboard backspace and esc then the results are outside the list then the message box appears and  I want to not allow the user to leave that combobox until a valid input is entered. Please guide me